# Why do a few of the LEDs in my lamp stay on at very dim light?

Tags: lighting, led

Bough this [lumiere](https://www.topelighting.com/en/products/sopot-round-led-ceiling-light/2x48w-led-round-ceiling-luminaire-sopot) for my room, but have one question. When I flip a switch on and on remote of the lamp OFF, most of LEDs turn off, but in first line of LEDs four of them dim out to like few percent and in last line of LEDs 4 of them dim out the same. So those two groups of four LEDs don't turn off when I use remote and wall switch is on. Is this normal? Minor electricity has to be there so I can switch on with remote so lamp stays in like a sleep mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slightly different than most of the LED-style questions asking about the dim glow but has the same cause, most likely.

The remote may be using a very small amount of current to maintain its functionality.  This small amount is enough to make some LED’s glow.

To eliminate the glow, a different remote that is compatible with LED’s will be needed, or in some cases, an incandescent lamp in one of the positions will do the trick.

We can not detect the tiny amount of power being used with an incandescent, but the LED’s are so efficient, they glow because of the remote power usage.

Comment: Thank you. But its safe? It is not going to short out or fry anything?  Light is very weak, im just worried about safety.

Comment: @MārtiņšDaugins I guessed it was a light fitting with LED lamps added, but no its a LED based fitting from the start.  One would presume the design takes their LEDs into account.  Ultimately the manufacturer/maker or the supplier would have a definitive answer.  It's possible the weak light is like a night-light mode, perhaps check the manual.

Comment: Yes this is safe, it is a very small amount of current, I have some customers that don’t want to spend the extra for led compatible controls and have had the same glow for years, no problem at all. That amount of power was wasted with incandescent now you get a little light. No safety issues at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys, for help with info.